# Transposing Crosstab in SAP business Object Design Studio

Tags: business-objects

This is my crosstab :

```
ColumnA ColumnB
    X   D
    Y   E
    Z   F
```

I want it to be converted to :

```
ColumnA X   Y   Z
ColumnB D   E   F
```

I checked all the properties and checked for CSS but did not find anything on this topic!

Answer (score 0):

Select your original table in webi report, right click the block, select "Turn into " option, then select "Horizontal Table" option. You will get the expected result.

Comment: I am not using Webi report, it is SAP Business Object Design Studio!